Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct username and password with the "manager-script"
I am using jdk 17, tomcat 10.1.17 and netbeans IDE 17. When running any project, the "Authentication required" dialog box always appears to ask me to enter username and password. Even though I entered it correctly, it does not work and keeps asking me to re-enter it. When I close the dialog box, the output message is:
Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct username and password with the "manager-script" role in the Tomcat customizer in the Server Manager.
See the server log for details.
When I close the dialog box, the output message is:
Properties: 
tomcat-users.xml file in cof folder: 
after some observation i realized when i start the server it will give this error:
WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.filterLockedAccounts An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user [admin]
I have tried methods such as deleting and reinstalling, running Netbeans with administrator rights, editing the tomcat-users.xml file, changing the server port, switching from "Use system proxy settings" to "No proxy" but they all do not work. Hope to receive the fastest help

Your tomcat-users.xml is not correct. You need to declare the roles (and obviously use the correct tag tomcat-users and not brokenDocument):
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user name="sa" password="123" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>

See also: https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/conf/tomcat-users.xml
Besides that: please don't post screenshots of text.

Thank you very much it works. I am very sorry for the inconvenience but i don't know how to add image. When i add image it turns into link

@NguyenDanhHuyK18HL You misunderstood me. You shouldn't use images at all :) Reasons (and exceptions) can be found here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/875083 And if you feel your question is answered it's nice to accept by clicking on the check mark (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
